# Download link in template, when you have a model object with a filefield

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is it possible to make a download link in a html template, when you have a model object available, like this?

models.py

```
class Barcard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    drinks = models.ManyToManyField(Drink)
    barcardFile = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='barcard') 
    mixingFile = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='mixing')
```

views.py

```
def download(request, barcard_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        barcard = get_object_or_404(Barcard, pk=barcard_id)
        return render(request, 'drinks/download.html', {'barcard':barcard})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/drinks/')
```

template/drinks/download.html

```
{% extends "drinks/base.html" %}
{% block fulltitle %}Drinks{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ barcard.name }}</h1>
    <p> Download barkort her: <a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ barcard.barcardFile.relative_path }}'>{{barcard.name}} barkort</a> </p>
    <p> Download blandekort her: <a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ barcard.mixingFile.relative_path }}'>{{barcard.name}} blandekort</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Right now I don't get a file, when clicking the link. Have I missed something or will I have to do something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think there is a `relative_path` attribute? You need to use the `url` attribute, which includes the media_url prefix.

```
<a href='{{ barcard.barcardFile.url }}'>
```

See [the FileField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField).

Comment: This worked, thanks. Regarding the `relative_path` attribute, I was looking at someone else's code, but couldn't get it to work. Missed that they had defined a function `relative_path(self)`. This solution thou is much more what i wanted. ;)